# Navigate through folder like Mac in win8 or use alternative

Tags: macos, ubuntu, windows-8, mac, user-experience

The Mac way of navigating file
[image]
 is making SOOO much sense than windows way of opening a gazillions of windows and confuse myself...

I wonder as a Windows8 user, is there way to make windows folder navigation simulate the same way as Mac folder navigation? Does using Ubuntu will be the best alternative than the hackintosh?

**NOTE: I am willing to switch system if any of that provide navigation similar to mac (just not mac itself, as its really really over my budget).**
Thank You

Comment: I find that using folders in tree view in the left pane is just as convenient as the Mac method - even better if there are a lot of directory levels. Or you could look at http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/ to see if anything takes your fancy.

Comment: @AFH I dont know if you feel it, some other thing to mention that, the switching between apps in Mac is so logical that when press alt+` will switching between the same app's various windows. Windows8 seems does not have such function, did you find such function in win8? Thanks!

Comment: **Alt-Tab** and **Alt-Esc** switch between windows: the first gives a menu that you can step through, the second switches immediately to the next in order. These are usually from different applications, as most Windows programs have only a single window which can gain focus to the exclusion of any others. Programs such as browsers which require multiple windows generally use tabs instead of separate windows. By the way you can add **Shift-** to the shortcuts to negotiate the windows in reverse order.

Comment: @AFH Maybe I did not explain it... What I mean is that, for example, when you have two chrome windows open, when in Mac, you can limit oneself to switch between those two window of the app without affecting the rest of the windows from other applications. That's the function of switching that I think Win8 lacks

Comment: I don't know about a keyboard shortcut to switch between an app's multiple windows in Windows, but you can hover over any of the app's icons in the toolbar/taskbar, and see an image of each window.  Click one to switch.  Note that the Mac does have a shortcut for this "Aero peek" (?) feature, it's usually F10, and it's very handy once you start using it!

Comment: I did understand you, but generally it is not something I find I need to do in Windows. I have never liked grouping on the taskbar, but that might offer some of what you want. Certainly the **Alt-Tab** menu allows you quickly to see which programs have the same icon, and skip the others.